# Does the BitBook have any significant meaning?

Tags: tiny-tower

Playing [tiny-tower](/questions/tagged/tiny-tower), I often read the bitbook in hopes of getting some helpful info for gameplay. Often it's filled with random crap that appears meaningless, but sometimes there are nuggets that I presume are to be valuable info.

Just today the bitbook said the following:

> **Miriam Webster:** *I hope I Don't have to work at the Fortune Teller too long. :(*

The interesting part of this however is that the `Fortune Teller` is `Miriam Webster's` `"Dream Job"`... What gives? Is it because her skill level is 4 for that particular industry? If so, should I be letting her go?

---

Here's what the wiki has to say about the **bitbook**

> As Bitizens are deep, complicated creatures, they have their own Facebook, too. They announce news about their employment, stocking and roommates, wonder aloud about the nature of their existence, and admit to playing other NimbleBit games on the job.
>   As Bitizens are complicated and thoughtful creatures like us humans, they need a place to vent and share their thoughts with friends. BitBook, the Bitizen version of a social networking service, was invented for that very purpose.
>   Bitizens will post on BitBook at random times, even (actually, mostly) on the job.
>   The pixely little people will post useful information, too, such as "Waiting for a shipment at the Diner, will have to close up!", "I work at the Bank, but it's closed today", or even the more rare "I love lamp." Admittedly, that last one wasn't so useful, but Bitizens are just that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Bit-Book' is to Bitizens (the little employees that stay in your tiny tower) as Facebook is to (IRL) humans.  The feeds posted in your bit book are, on average, **just jokes**.

Although, in some  cases you will see your employees / residents posting relevant information (for example, in your case), such as "I hate my job".  This just means that they have a skill level of 5 or lower in that current position and/or they have a higher skill in a different job type.

*My recommendation* for your scenario would be to just keep that employee in your Fortune Teller floor for the double stock bonus and just wait for someone else with a higher skill & Dream Job of Fortune Teller to replace that employee (as you already received the tiny buck bonus).

Answer (score 1):

The BitBook gives a little more personality to your Bitizens. It can alert you about important stuff like floors that need restocking or Bitizens who aren't in their preferred jobs, but this info is available in much more readable fashion on the tower itself (via the restock icons) or the Bitizen list which can be sorted by happiness (happiness = bitizens unemployed, employed and employed in their dream jobs).

In my personal opinion it can be completely ignored (I have over 10K notifications there).

What your bitizen said shouldn't worry you (unless you have sympathy for virtual people). A Bitizen with a low skill level will never be happy in it's job, even if it's his dream job, and there isn't a known way to increase a Bitizen's skill.

Comment: So basically there's just no way to make a low skill bitizen happy, even if they're in their dream job.

Comment: As far as I know, no.